# Denying access to videos and audio directly from browser. Only thru main website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have been browsing similar questions here but i haven't found my specific scenario.

I have domain.com. I have video.domain.com.

Now, before I continue, I am going to clarify. I am not trying to "protect" my video from being "stolen". This is virtually impossible.

I just don't want direct access to it in order to avoid leeching or downloads. My intention is to "protect" this video from unauthorized access (login and password will do for the website), but of course, if I don't do RTMP (which I intend to do) you got in your browser the full address of the video.

video.domain.com/course/1/Intro.mp4.

and that would not stop you from downloading it directly.

So, I tried a couple of things but didn't seem to work.

First, URL Rewrite. I am using IIS 7. I tried to block any request that {HTTP_REFERRER} was different than domain.com. Didn't work. Yes, it did block me from download it, but that's because my {HTTP_REFERRER} was empty. Which is also empty when domain.com try to access my subdomain. So, it did block the download but also to be able to play it from my website.

So, that, didn't work.

Next, I tried some IP Address Domain and Restrictions but didn't work either.

Has someone be able to do this successfully? I know amazon services are able to do this successfully but I can't think of a way.

Thank you

Comment: you can use HTTP modules for responding requests of video mime type and also use ASP.net form authentication for your video folders so that no one would be able to access your vides directly from the browser

Comment: Hello Patel. That would work if i had the videos in the same website. In my case, videos.domain.com is just a site to serve these files. So, .NET authentication would have not had any effect on videos.domain.com. I added the solution below. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION.

So, at the IIS level, in my videos.domain.com site, I created an URL Rewrite Rule where every request to a MP4 triggers this verification.

1. No empty Referer (if you call the video from video.domain.com/..../Intro.mp4, then it would not have a Referer).
2. Match ONLY "http://domain.com". If it doesn't match that, it would not serve the video. It would serve an image saying "Do not steal the videos" :)

Very simple.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="ONLY from DOMAIN.COM" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(?:mp4)$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$" />
          <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^http://domain\.com/.*$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://videos.domain.com/leechingisbad.jpg" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```